# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'. Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

Reading data from Excel is not showing `double` fields latitude and longitude. I have tried using both `string` and `Double`. If I use `string` I get the error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'.

If I use `double?` I'm not getting any error and fields are showing blank in the `DataGridView`.

```
private struct GIS
{
    public string AccountNo;
    public string MeterNo;
    public string Mobile;
    public string Name;
    public string GeoCode;
    public string Welaiyh;
    public string Area;
    public string Region;
    public string Xcord;
    public string Ycord;
    public Double? Longitude;
    public Double? Latitude;
    //public string Longitude;
    //public string Latitude;
    public DateTime? Createddate;
    public string Status;
}

List<GIS> xl = xlDT.AsEnumerable().Select(g => new GIS()
{
    AccountNo = g.Field<string>("Account No"),
    MeterNo = g.Field<string>("Meter No#"),
    Mobile = g.Field<string>("Mobile "),
    Name = g.Field<string>(" Name"),
    GeoCode = g.Field<string>("Geo Code"),
    Welaiyh = g.Field<string>("Welaiyh"),
    Area = g.Field<string>("Area"),
    Region = g.Field<string>("Region"),
    Xcord = g.Field<string>("X-Coordinate"),
    Ycord = g.Field<string>("Y-Coordinate"),
    Longitude = g.Field<Double?>("Longitude")??0,
    Latitude = g.Field<Double?>("Latitude") ??0,
    Createddate = g.Field<DateTime?>("Created On"),
    Status = g.Field<string>("Status (Account No#)")
}).ToList();
```

Comment: AFAIK, the default Excel data type for numeric cells assigned as `double`, so it is proper way to use `double` instead of `string`. Check if `g.Field<double>("[columnname]")` contains null value instead of any number when converting `DataTable` to `List`.

Comment: When i am using double getting error Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Double'. Please use a nullable type.

Comment: I see that when changing to `double` instead of `double?` indicates presence of null value in `DataTable`. `g.Field<double?>("[columnname]")` is already right here to prevent wrong null-value cast, is that `DataGridView` displays empty value instead of zero (defined by null-coalescing operator)?

Comment: var longg = (object)DBNull.Value;           
                if (m.Longitude != null)
                {                                      
                    longg = m.Longitude; 
                }
                else
                    longg = DBNull.Value;

Comment: In data grid view i have used the above code.It is displaying 0 and where data exist as empty

Comment: Well, you have mixed numeric & character (i.e. string) values in `Latitude` & `Longitude` columns, try using `IMEX=1` in Excel connection string with `Extended Properties` & see if the `double` values are parsed properly.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to test the field for null before attempting to assign.  So use this instead (assuming you want to show 0 where null):

```
Longitude = g.IsNull("Longitude") ? 0.0 : g.Field<Double>("Longitude"),
Latitude = g.IsNull("Latitude") ? 0.0 : g.Field<Double>("Latitude"),
```

Comment: @Sibghat It works fine in my test.  You must have something else wrong.  What values are in your spreadsheet?

Comment: Longitude                         Latitude
2162078.24                         520195.95
20d 39 17.2979280000055 58d 52 31.4824080000011
0                                         0

Comment: Is that `20d` & `58d` used to mark double values instead of mixed numeric-string values? If you want to parse mixed values as string change the connection string extended properties for Excel import.

Comment: Please put a break in your code after you have filled your DataTable, and check the contents of your Latitude and Longitude values for Rows[1].  I am pretty sure the OleDbAdapter will treat them as nulls

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto  my connection string xlConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + textselect.Text + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;'";

Comment: @Sibghat Try changing to this: `@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + textselect.Text + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;'";` (add IMEX setting, I think conversion to string is more preferred than double for mixed values).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto His problem is with his spreadsheet.  He needs to sort out his formatting of a number in the spreadsheet to show degrees longitude/latitude and then there is no problem with mixed string / number

Comment: @JonathanWillcock what do you mean by sorting in excel file?

Comment: @Sibghat Sorry bad choice of word. I said sort out. It means fix or correct.